# Передача файлов(больше 5 мб) сервер->клиент Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, клиент-сервер, indy

Подскажите какими компонентами лучше воспользоваться чтобы передавать файлы от сервера до клиента по ЛОКАЛЬНОЙ СЕТИ в DElphi. пробовал через инди, пробовал через сокеты. В сокетах ограничение по объему, файл не доходит полностью. В инди я не могу забиндить передачу файлов на кнопку, т.к. требуется поток. Может я смотрю не в ту сторону.

Comment: Может большие файлы для передачи нужно делить на более мелкие кусочки?

Comment: TcpServer, не?
Тут и пример есть.
http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showpost.php?p=64145&postcount=6

Comment: @K_NoW к сожалению, пример плохой и не учитывает очень многое, что может случиться с данными по дороге. Он подходит только для обмена в пределах локальной машины.

Answer (score 4):

Основываясь на утверждении

> В сокетах ограничение по объему

предположу, что передачу/прием данных планируется вести по протоколу TCP. Соответственно, всё дальнейшее будет основываться на этом утверждении.

**Изначально**: TCP-протокол - это потоковый двунаправленный протокол, у него нет ограничений на объем передаваемых данных. Ограничение по объему есть у буферов сокета, они выставляются в реестре [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985816/change-default-socket-buffer-size-under-windows). Злоупотреблять этим параметром (да и вообще трогать его) не следует - какое бы значение вы ни выставили, все равно рано или поздно обнаружится такой набор, который не уложится в отведенный лимит.

Поэтому общий принцип работы по TCP был, есть и останется следующий:

1. отправляем данные в буфер до тех пор, пока он их принимает.
2. Запоминаем позицию, на которой остановились
3. Ждем сигнала от сокета о том, что буфер свободен и возвращаемся к п.1

В качестве примера можно посмотреть, как устроен модуль ScktComp, а конкретнее - методы класса `TCustomWinSocket` - `SendStream` -> `Event`->`SendStreamPiece` (они работают именно в такой последовательности).

При использовании наследников `TStream` - задача даже упрощается, поскольку позиция запоминается самим TStream (нужно только не забывать, что если отправилось данных меньше, чем было считано - перевести `TStream.Position` назад на эту разницу).

Необходимо также обращать внимание, что все методы отправки данных в сокет и получения их из сокета - это функции и они возвращают количество **реально** прочитанных/записанных данных. Ориентироваться можно только на их результаты, предположение "я отправил в буфер 100 байт" совершенно не означает, что они все ушли в сокет.

**Дополнение 1**
По умолчанию у TCP-сокетов включен алгоритм Нагла. Если вкратце, это означает, что отправленные данные улетают не сразу, а после определенного таймаута и таким образом короткие посылки могут склеиться друг с другом. Например, если отправить "123" и следом "456", то в сеть уйдет посылка "123456". Если передатчик и приемник расположены на одной локальной машине, то этот эффект не будет проявляться.

**Дополнение 2** Даже если посылки ушли отдельно, то из-за пропускной способности сети, сетевого оборудования и других факторов на приемном конце они могут склеиться друг с другом. Пример из "дополнения 1" также актуален, только возможны и другие варианты - "1234" и следом "56", "12" и следом "3456" и тому подобное.

Единственное, в чем вы можете быть абсолютно уверены - посылки никогда не перепутаются местами. В какой последовательности было отправлено, в такой же и придет.

Посему, достаточно стандартной практикой при работе по TCP является предварение собственно данных каким-либо служебным заголовком, который как минимум содержит длину передаваемой информации в поле фиксированной длины (например - Int64 - 8 байт).

Конкретная реализация, естественно, может и будет отличаться в зависимости от способа взаимодействия.

**Дополнение 3** Чтобы избежать подобных проблем, можно использовать протоколы, где всё вышеозвученное уже реализовано: HTTP, FTP...

Вам необходимо:

1. Определиться, какой протокол вы будете использовать (по исходной постановке вопроса совершенно неочевидно, что кроме содержимого файлов должно будет передаваться по сети)
2. Определиться с набором компонентов (ScktComp, Indy, ICS...)
3. Посмотреть примеры их использования и попробовать выполнить собственную реализацию
4. Если остались вопросы/что-то не получается - задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Передавать только файлы, но именно от сервера к клиентам

Comment: @МаксимКутенков  В таком случае (имхо), вам действительно больше всего подойдет TCP, поскольку этот протокол позволяет инициацию обмена (не путать с инициацией подключения) сервером. По поводу компонентов - мне сложно что-то советовать, т.к. все время работал только через стандартные TClient\TServerSocket из ScktComp.pas в неблокирующем режиме. Есть и своя достаточно простая реализация, но она не пойдет для ваших нужд, т.к. основывается на TMemoryStream, в который гигабайтные фильмы лучше не запихивать.

Answer (score 2):

- Разделяйте большие файлы на мелкие куски и передавайте их, потом собирайте обратно.
- Научитесь работать с потоками и используйте Инди

Comment: Можете поделиться ссылочкой или кодом, где описан алгоритм деления?

Comment: @МаксимКутенков Это скорее всего отдельный вопрос. Как и вопрос про работу с потоками. Алгоритм простой - копируем кусок, отправляем его с пометкой о его порядковом номере. При приеме получаем все куски и копируем из них обратно в большой файл по порядку.

Comment: вот точно не нужно "добавлять к кускам порядковый номер". Если используется tcp, то данные придут в том порядке, в котором были отправлены. Если они придут не по порядку, то это будет мегабага и тут уже будут и Майкрософт, и Линус, и Кук, и многое другие интересоваться.

Comment: Зачем разделять данные на куски? Разве что для параллельной передачи разных данных через одно соединение. А так - как только передающий буфер сокета освободится - записывается туда "сколько влезет" из TFileStream и всё. Насчет Indy - не согласен. Да, это частично холивар, но есть не мало других наборов компонентов, не уступающих по функционалу и значительно проще реализованных.

Comment: @kami про TCP нигде не сказано. Разделять на куски т.к. у автора "В сокетах ограничение по объему, файл не доходит полностью". В любом случае, вопрос слишком расплывчат, чтобы давать точные ответы.

Comment: @Kromster Это автор думает, что у сокетов есть ограничение по объему :). На самом деле ограничение есть только у буферов сокета  Естественно, что большой объем информации не запихнуть в сокет сразу. Но ничего не мешает досылать данные, когда буфер освободится. И разделение на куски не нужно - просто отправлять данные с текущей позиции TStream-а до тех пор, пока буфер опять не забьется. Собственно, в `TCustomWinSocket` именно так и сделан метод отправки потока. В остальном - согласен, как минимум не указан протокол обмена (TCP/HTTP/FTP...), чтобы можно было дать конкретные рекомендации.