# Склеивание(TCP)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcp

Переводил свой чат с UDP на TCP и столкнулся с тем, что пакеты данных по пути к серверу склеиваются и наоборот от сервера к клиенту.
Алгоритм решения проблемы составить не смог, примеров и информацию также не нашел.

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
Var MemoryBuffer: string;
    i, p: integer;
    MemoryChange: string;
    login, password, UserSender, UserClientMessage, TextMessage, lastUserConnect: string;
    NewUser: boolean;
begin
    MemoryBuffer:= Socket.ReceiveText;

    if Copy(MemoryBuffer,1,9) = '[Request]' then//проверка на команду в пришедших данных
    begin
       ...//Обработка полученных  данных(как клиент, так и сервер по такому принципу)
    end;
```

Comment: Что именно вы хотите решить, в чем проблема? В TCP обычно достаточно писать свои заголовки пакетам - длину+тело. Также можете отключить алгоритм Нагеля, чтобы TCP не ждал еще пакетов перед отправкой, а отправлял сразу.

Comment: я не понимаю как это реализовывается. То что слова могут отправляться отрывками, собираться в буфер я понимаю, но как это в коде реализовать я не понимаю.

Comment: ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
Var MemoryBuffer: string;
    i, p: integer;
    MemoryChange: string;
    login, password, UserSender, UserClientMessage, TextMessage, lastUserConnect: string;
    NewUser: boolean;
begin                                                                                                                        MemoryBuffer:= Socket.ReceiveText;
if Copy(MemoryBuffer,1,9) = '[Request]' then//Тут проверяю текст на команды и прочее, которые просит выполнить клиент.(со стороны клиента также идет чтение(read))

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код

Comment: Вы совершенно правы с проблемой разбиения и склейки пакетов! При (особенно) интенсивном обмене и разбиваться и склеиваться может как угодно, единственное - не меняется последовательность отправки / приема. В "голом TCP" с текстом работать нельзя, нужно работать с последовательностью  байт, имеющих заголовок. Например: https://github.com/kami-soft/SimpleTCPComponents  Относительно развернутый ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529962/192901

Comment: Что значит "склеиваются"? Данные одного IP-пакета переставлются во второй, после этого первый выбрасывается и получается один пакет из двух? Так не бывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код но только инди, но отличий от SocketServer не много(наименование функций) - суть та же будет и у вас...
Пакет передается видом:
Первый байт - айди пакета(можно 2-3-4-XX байт, сколько типов пакетов вам надо)
Второй и третий байты(мне нужны сообщения в несколько десятков КБ) - размер пакета.

```
Var
  b:Byte;
begin
  while Sock.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size>0 do
  Begin
    b:=Sock.IOHandler.ReadByte;
    // расшифровываем \ распаковываем байт - если необходимо
    SocketStream.Write(b,1);
    if (pSize=0)and(SocketStream.Size>2) then
    Begin
      SocketStream.Position:=0;
      SocketStream.Read(pOpcode,1);
      SocketStream.Read(pSize,4);
      SocketStream.Position:=SocketStream.Size;
    End;
    if (pSize>0)and(SocketStream.Size=pSize) then
    Begin
//     << Обработка вашего "сообщения(пакета)" >>;
      pSize := 0;
      SocketStream.clear;
    End; 
  End;
end;

SocketStream - TMemoryStream - буфер для сборки пакета.
pSize        - Word          - Размер собираемого пакета(который ждем)
pOpCode      - Byte          - Тип ожидаемого пакета.
```

Для всех кто соберется критиковать сборку пакета по байту - мне она необходима, т.к. в моем коде используется потоковое сжатие и шифрование, с входом какраз в 1 байт.. 
Автор вопроса волен ожидать хоть весь пакет если ему это(обработка каждого байта отдельно) не нужно. Код для ожидания всего пакета - переделать не сложно